# How to set "ApplicationID" on LoginButton control? (Facebook SDK .Net)

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm following the login tutorial on [facebooksdk.net](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/login/) to implement their login button user control, but after referencing the library and adding the `LoginButton` I can't find a ApplicationId property as shown in the tutorial.

To debug this, I've searched through the properties available and tried referencing both namespaces, but each button control doesn't give an ApplicationId property. Also tried declaring the `ApplicationId="*****"` in the
xaml declaration of the control to no avail.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

This is how I've declared the namespace and control in the View:

```
<Page
    x:Class="LC_Points.View.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LC_Points.View"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"
    xmlns:facebookControls="using:Facebook.Client.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">



        <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">

            <facebookControls:LoginButton 
            x:Name="loginButton" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The library I've referenced from Nuget:

```
Install-Package Facebook.Client -pre
```

And a snapshot of my source tree showing the referenced libraries:

[image: refs]

And this is the property for the LoginButton, showing no ApplicationId property, I've added the LoginButton from both the `Controls` and `facebookControls` namespaces but neither give this property:

[image: props]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following page:

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/

And configure your app. Since v1.0.0 of the sdk we use the config files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across the same issue, it seems that the current solution on [facebooksdk.net](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/login/) is aimed at older versions of the SDK.

The following solution using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` to perform Authentication is the most up to date solution for Windows Universal Apps:

[Integrating Facebook authentication in Universal Windows apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2015/02/12/integrating-facebook-authentication-in-universal-windows-apps.aspx)

```
private async Task Login()
{
    //Facebook app id
    var clientId = "*************";
    //Facebook permissions
    var scope = "public_profile, email";

    var redirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
    {
        client_id = clientId,
        redirect_uri = redirectUri,
        response_type = "token",
        scope = scope
    });

    Uri startUri = loginUrl;
    Uri endUri = new Uri(redirectUri, UriKind.Absolute);

    //Avvio l'operazione di autenticazione
    WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, endUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

WebAuthenticationBroker  broker support only windows phone 8.1
How to use fb on windows phone 8 and how to get login user details?